# Spark broadcast a trained tensorflow SavedModel

Tags: python, apache-spark, tensorflow

I have a trained SavedModel. I am trying to broadcasted the loaded model in spark but get this error from the pyspark/broadcast.py -

```
raise pickle.PicklingError(msg)
_pickle.PicklingError: Could not serialize broadcast: TypeError: can't pickle _thread.RLock objects
```

The code I have to load and boradcast -

```
import tensorflow as tf
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = (
    SparkSession
    .builder
    .getOrCreate()
    )

model = tf.keras.models.load_model(saved_model_path, compile=False)
spark.sparkContext.broadcast(model) #<--- this is where it fails
```

I tried to pickle the model to verify and as expected, it gave error as well.

```
import pickle
with open("model.pkl", 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(model, f)
```

It appears to me that the SavedModel cannot be pickled. Similar code works just fine for a h5 model. Now if SavedModel cannot be pickled and to broadcast it needs to be pickled, what are my options?

Thanks.

Comment: Hi @NITS, were you able to solve this problem? I am also facing a similar issue,

Answer (score 2):

You can use the concept of sparkFiles to send the model files to all the worker nodes and then load the model from inside a pandas udf

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = (
    SparkSession
    .builder
    .getOrCreate()
    )


spark.sparkContext.addFile(saved_model_path)


@pandas_udf(return_type, PandasUDFType.GROUPED_MAP)
def predict(data):

    from tensorflow as tf

    model_file_local = SparkFiles.get(filename)
    model = tf.keras.models.load_model(model_file_local, compile=False)
    model.predict(data)
```