# ValueError: When input_signature is provided, all inputs to the Python function must be convertible to tensors:

Tags: python, tensorflow, pyspark, word2vec, tensorflow-hub

I have pyspark df like this:

```
id        desc
1      abd hdbh jbj
2      sgjhd jhdgh gjhg
3      bvj hvhgvgh
4      jkjb bhj
```

Now I want to convert my `desc` column to vector so I'm using Google sentence encoder as udf, here's my code:

```
module_url = "https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder/4"
model = hub.load(module_url)

def embedding(input):
    return (model[input])

df.withColumn("Embedding", list(embedding(f.lit("desc"))))
```

Here's the error log:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_13810/1173342766.py in <module>
----> 1 df_shirt_sample.withColumn("Embedding", list(embedding(f.lit("desc"))))

/tmp/ipykernel_13810/446837446.py in embedding(input)
      1 def embedding(input):
----> 2     return (model(input))

~/miniconda3/envs/dev_env_37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/saved_model/load.py in _call_attribute(instance, *args, **kwargs)
    684 
    685 def _call_attribute(instance, *args, **kwargs):
--> 686   return instance.__call__(*args, **kwargs)
    687 
    688 

~/miniconda3/envs/dev_env_37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/traceback_utils.py in error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
    151     except Exception as e:
    152       filtered_tb = _process_traceback_frames(e.__traceback__)
--> 153       raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
    154     finally:
    155       del filtered_tb

~/miniconda3/envs/dev_env_37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function_spec.py in _convert_inputs_to_signature(inputs, input_signature, flat_input_signature)
    521         need_packing = True
    522       except ValueError:
--> 523         raise ValueError("When input_signature is provided, all inputs to "
    524                          "the Python function must be convertible to "
    525                          "tensors:\n"

ValueError: When input_signature is provided, all inputs to the Python function must be convertible to tensors:
  inputs: (
    Column<b'desc'>)
  input_signature: (
    TensorSpec(shape=<unknown>, dtype=tf.string, name=None)).
```

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to load the model from a UDF following this post: [Spark broadcast a trained tensorflow SavedModel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63929473/spark-broadcast-a-trained-tensorflow-savedmodel). This will load a model on each worker and then you can make the predictions.

Example:

```py
import tensorflow_hub as hub
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.types import ArrayType, FloatType


def embedding(x):
    model_url = "https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder/4"
    model = hub.load(model_url, tags=["serve"])
    return model([x])


@F.udf(returnType=ArrayType(ArrayType(FloatType())))
def infer(data):
    outputs = embedding(data)
    return outputs.numpy().tolist()


spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
data = [{"text": "abd hdbh jbj"}]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data=data)
df = df.withColumn("embedding", infer("text"))
df.show(10)
df.printSchema()
```

Which gives:

```
+------------+--------------------+                                             
|        text|           embedding|
+------------+--------------------+
|abd hdbh jbj|[[0.054931916, -0...|
+------------+--------------------+

root
 |-- text: string (nullable = true)
 |-- embedding: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: array (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- element: float (containsNull = true)
```

Check out the *Guide to Deploying a TF 2.0 SavedModel on Spark using PySpark*: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/31421

Another way to do this is to use Petastorm to convert the Spark Dataframe to TensorFlow Dataframe and then feed it to a distributed model, please see: https://www.databricks.com/notebooks/simple-aws/petastorm-spark-converter-tensorflow.html

Comment: Hi I'm getting this error. Do you know what might be wrong?

PickleError: can't pickle repeated message fields, convert to list first

Comment: @Chris_007 I had that issue before moving the `hub.load` into a function. Did you run the exact code that I provided? Please provide the tensorflow and pyspark versions so I can compare to my environment.

Comment: @vlasdsiv Hey that did solve my problem, but now I'm getting ``` ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow_hub' ```
Do I need to install tensorflow_hub in a different way for Pyspark df? Like it's working if I call function for string variable when I use it with pyspark df it's throwing error.

Comment: And also if I load model everytime inside function, then wouldn't it be much slow?

Comment: @Chris_007 Yep, that complicates stuff. If you are loading the model on each worker than your worker has to have that package installed. That's why you get No module error. Not sure if `hub.load` is using cache, either way it's not the most efficient way. I'll try to investigate also, for now I don't know what's the best solution.